# Why Javascript removed leading zeros from string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router to get the parameter value from url using `$stateParam`. One of the parameters is id number that may or may not begin with `00`. For example, `0034323343`. In this entire application, the leading zeros are intact. However, there's one instance where I'm adding state to an object like this:

```
SharedDataService.setBreadcrumb({
                state: 'notes({ claimID: ' + $stateParams.claimID + ', cardholderId: ' + $stateParams.cardholderId + ' })',
                name: 'Notes'
            });
```

For some reason, the leading zero is removed. The ID becomes `34323343` in the URL. I checked the `typeof($stateParams.cardholderId)` which returns `string`. So, why is zero missing?

Here's the object that is saved.

```
Object {state: "notes({ claimID: 187337, cardholderId: 0034323343 })", name: "Notes"}
```

which i printed out to the console when this value is set. See how the state has `cardholderId in` correct format - with leading zeros? Now, why does that change to int when I display it inside div. `{{ crumb.state }}`??

Comment: because you probably have  a number and not a string and numbers do not have leading and trailing zeros. Where is it being set?

Comment: what fills $stateParams.carholderId?  If it is a string when you get here, it must have been a number some place else.

Comment: $stateParams.cardholderId will be a string by that stage yes, but cardholderId was probably an int at the point where you pass the value to cause a route change (typically href or ui-sref).

Comment: cardholderId come from the database where it's set as string. I pass the cardholder Id to various views via $stateParam where all other views treat it as string so, the cardholderId has the leading zeros intact. I checked for the type right before setting the state in the code shown above; it returns string. I have not converted it to int anywhere. I'm confused.

Comment: For example, ` $state.go('details', { claimID: claimId, cardholderId:$stateParams.cardholderId, noteID: noteId + 1 });` code doesn't convert the $stateParams.cardholderId to int. The leading zeros are intact. So, what am I missing? In fact, I even created a string variable and stored the $stateParams.cardholderId to that variable. I then replced `$stateParams.cardholderId` with `cardholderId` local variable. It still converts it to int.

Comment: @AndyHasIt, you're right. That was spot on. I checked it, and turned out, when the value was passed to cause a route to change, I had to add `"` like @PavelGatnar suggested. I failed to see it. Great job guys!!! Thank you so much for pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enclose the variables with `"` to retain it as string in the stringified object.

```
'notes({ claimID: "' + $stateParams.claimID + '", cardholderId: "' + $stateParams.cardholderId + '" })'
```